# What shall I do in the middle of working on a feature branch, and can't compile my project without pulling and merging master to the feature branch?

Tags: git, merge

In a C# project repository,

- I created a feature branch from the master branch, and then did some work on the feature branch. At that point, I haven't `git add` or `git commit` my work yet.
- I tried to see if the C# project with my change could be compiled, but it couldn't. I then realized that some coworker has changed the master branch, so I checked out the master branch and ran `git pull` to update master, and then merged the master to my feature branch, where I solved some merge conflict manually. Then the C# project could be compiled. At this point, the unstaged changes consisted of both my work and my manual changes to resolve the merge conflict.
- Then I continued to work on my feature branch. After I finished, I ran `git add` and `git commit` to create a new commit consisting of all my work on the feature branch and my changes to resolve the merge conflict. Then I pushed my feature branch to GitHub, created a pull request to merge it to master on GitHub, and assigned a collaborator to review the pull request.

[Now I realize it is bad for the reviewer  to distinguish my work on the feature branch from my changes to resolve the merge conflict in the single commit, and it is better to create different commits to separate the changes for merge conflict and my work on the feature branch.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807021/how-shall-i-arrange-merge-from-the-master-branch-into-my-feature-branch-and-comm)

However, if I again encounter a similar case (i.e. in the middle of working on a feature branch, find that I can't compile my project without pulling master and merging it to the feature branch), I am not sure of how to separate changes for merging and changes for my work into different commits.
What shall i do then?

Thanks.

Comment: My advice would be to rebase your local feature branch onto the tip of master, before pushing it in for the first time. Since no one has seen it yet, you're only rewriting history in your local clone, for the sake of a cleaner history in the shared repository.

Answer (score 1):

This answer has two parts: 1. How to fix the situation at hand, and 2. how to avoid the same problem in the future. These two parts require quite different approaches.

---

Fixing the situation at hand.

The problem is, that you have published a commit that contains changes that were already included in some other commit. This is bad, as it will generate merge conflicts later on.

To fix the situation, you need to recreate your feature branch from the right base commit. You can do this with the following commands:

```
git checkout feature-broken
# git status to ensure that the working directory and index are clean
git reset --mixed <the-commit-you-actually-want-to-base-your-work-on>
# git status and git diff, to see what changes your feature branch actually wanted to introduce
git checkout -b feature-repaired
git add ...
git commit ...
```

In this sequence, you take the state of the working directory as your broken feature branch puts it, and create a different commit with the exact same contents but with a different parent commit. That is all the fix that you need (apart from retracting `feature-broken`, of course).

I'm not certain, which base commit you actually want to use, though. Your question sounds like you had no previous work committed on your broken feature branch yet, in that case the base commit to use would be `master`. If you already had committed work on your broken feature branch, you will have created a merge commit that munches your changes with the conflict resolution. In that case, you should first create a clean merge commit for your previously committed changes, and base the `git reset --mixed` on that new commit.

---

How to avoid this in the future.

The answer is `git stash`. Before you pull your upstream changes, simply issue a `git stash` to get your local changes out of the way. Once you are on the correct commit to base your work upon, just do a `git stash pop` to get your local changes back (fixing any merge conflicts that you encounter).